# Function evaluation disabled, Error in VS 2015 on Query LinQ Execution?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, linq, c#-4.0

I run this code:

```
var output = from data in myDataList 
             from engName in dtarrennames 
             from pename in dtarrpenames 
             where data.exactName == engName 
             select pename;
```

we have two array of strings `dtarrennames, dtarrpenames` and want to extract `pename` such that `engName == data.exactName` from `myDataList`.

When Debug this and click to see result get usual error `function evaluation disabled.`

UPDATE 1:

the `dtarrpenames` and `dtarrennames` are 1D string array and the `myDataList` is an array of a class

I tryied it like this :

```
var output = from data in myDataList
             join engName in dtarrennames
             on data.exactName equals engName
             join pename in dtarrpenames       
             on engName equals pename
             select new { pename, engName };
```

but there no output.

Update 2:

this is my structure:

```
class MyData
{
    public string exactName = "";
    public string Id = "";
}

string[] dtarrennames = new string[] { "enn1", "enn2", "enn3" };
string[] dtarrpenames=new string[] { "pen1","pen2","pen3" };
MyData[] myDataList = new MyData[n] {...};
```

How to solve this?

Comment: What's the relation between `dtarrennames` and `dtarrpenames`?

Comment: @AjayGupta dtarrennames is English name and dtarrpenames is German names with same id.

Comment: engName represents a row of the data table dtarrennames therefore you cannot make comparison between a row value and a field value as in the statement "where data.exactName == engName", you should also include the relation between dtarrpenames and the other tables in your query.

Comment: @AbdullahDibas see my updates. this is string array not data table.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `dtarrennames` and `dtarrpenames` have properties `Id` and `Name`, the following should work.

```
    var output = from data in myDataList 
                 join engName in dtarrennames
                 on data.exactName equals engName.Name 
                 join pename in dtarrpenames 
                 on engName.Id equals pename.Id
                 select new { pename, engName };
```

EDIT:

The following should work based upon the updated question.

```
        string[] dtarrennames = new string[] { "enn1", "enn2", "enn3" };
        string[] dtarrpenames = new string[] { "pen1", "pen2", "pen3" };
        var values = dtarrennames.Zip(dtarrpenames, (x, y) => new { dtarrenname = x, dtarrpename = y });
        MyData[] myDataList = new MyData[1] { new MyData { exactName = "enn1", Id = "3" } };

        var output = (from data in myDataList
                     join engName in values
                     on data.exactName equals engName.dtarrenname
                     select engName).ToList();
```

`output` would contain a list of objects with two properties`dtarrenname, dtarrpename`.

Comment: I want to extract engName and pename like as two dimension array.

Comment: there is one update, pename, engname 1D array of strings.

Comment: You want to `pename.Name + engname.Name` or you want to concatenate the lists pename and engname. Please be clear

Comment: class MyData
{
 public string exactName="";
 public string Id="";
}

string[] dtarrennames=new string[] { "enn1","enn2","enn3" };
string[] dtarrpenames=new string[] { "pen1","pen2","pen3" };

MyData[] myDataList=new MyData[n]{...};

Comment: I wrote in the very first line of my answer that it'll work only if dtarrennames and dtarrpenames have properties Id and Name. See my update for the required answer.

Comment: You need `ToList` for `output` to contain data.

Comment: @GertArnold . . . Thank you!